# Grails project : Run As(run on server) vs Run As(run-app)

Tags: eclipse, grails, port

I am beginner with Grails Framework.
I have set port no into `BuildConfig.groovy` as `grails.server.port.http = 8090`

In **eclipse**,
When I run the project **as Run on Server** then it runs into `localhost:8080/`
But when I run the project **as Grails Command(run-app)** then it runs into `localhost:8090/`

What is the difference between them? How can I run into port **8090**: even I run as `run on server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run the project as Grails Command(run-app) then it runs into localhost:8090/ because that is the default port for grails.

If you are running the project as Run on Server then it runs into localhost:8080/ because it takes setting from server.xml.

To run it on 8090 you will have to change the port by editing server.xml file in your tomcat.

change in:::

```
<Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"   
           connectionTimeout="20000"   
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: What is the difference between run on server and run-app, is run-app will run using server or not

Comment: any way application runs of server but run app is for development.It uses embedded server.